# How do I get the list of permissions?

Tags: group

I am trying to use  the group method `hasPermission(permission_label, user)`. I found an example that  is the following:

```
$group->hasPersmission('administer members', $user)
```

I would like to know what all the different permissions types are. In particular I want to be able to differentiate whether a user can edit or just view a type of content.

How do I a get a list of the different types of permissions?

Thanks,

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Admin -> Group -> Group Types -> [your group type]. On that page, click the Permissions tab. You can see all the permissions there. If you need to know the permissions string, you can inspect any checkbox for a given role/permission combo, and look at the `name` attribute. It will be something like `admin[permission_label]`, where `permission_label` is the value you would pass as the first argument to `$group->hasPermission()`.

Comment: Is there an API cll to get this list ?